# Is a congregational prayer valid if the Imam isn't in his own row?

Tags: salat, jamaat, imam-al-jamaah

In our mosque, there isn't enough space to make two complete rows, so the Imam prays just one step in front of us (almost beside us), as in the following diagram:

[image: Like these lines here _______---_________ (--- this is the imam)]

Is this sort of congregational prayer allowed?

Comment: Is the space sufficient for the Imam to do Sajdah?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if situation doesn't support here in your case.
Related ruling, when two people pray together, they stand similarly like in your case.

[image]